# Sort a hash by value inside other hash - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash that contains another hash inside and I need to sort as follow:

```
data = {
    "user": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": "36",
    },
    "company": "Terminal",
    "country": "Canada",
} 
{
    "user": {
        "name": "Mary",
        "age": "32",
    },
    "company": "Brasco",
    "country": "Italy",
}
```

Using this way I can sort without problem:

```
data.sort_by { |a| [a[:company], a[:country]] }
```

But in case "company" and "country" have the same value, I need to sort by a third option, the "name".

The case is that I need to use the function 'reverse' at the end (the example I posted is not the real situation, the real one is too big...lol).

So the result is sorting the name reversed too.

```
data.sort_by { |a| [a['company'], a['country'], a['user']['name']] }.reverse
```

I need the "company" and "country" sort in DESC and user.name sort by ASC.

Comment: Would you please provide a valid input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.sort_by { |a| [a['company'], a['country'], a['user']['name']] }
```

When `sort_by` receives an array, it compares each element when the previous ones tie.

If you want to sort `company ASC, country ASC, name ASC` and then easily reverse it to `company DESC, country DESC, name ASC` you can do this:

```
sorted = data.group_by do |x| 
  [x['company'], x['country']] 
end.each do |k, v| 
  v.sort_by! { |x| x[:user][:name] } 
end.sort_by(&:first).map(&:last)
```

This creates an array of arrays, each internal array contains all the users in the company/country pair, sorted by name.

now to get the ASC option you should do:

```
sorted.flatten
```

and the reverse (where users are still ASC) you need to:

```
sorted.reverse.flatten
```

Comment: @SérgioToledo please tell me how this failed, so I can check the discrepancy. It should work fine.

Comment: You're right @UriAgassi, but I need something more. I edited the question and put more information.

Comment: Great @UriAgassi, you solved the problem!
And thank for the method ".flatten", I'll use it in other part of the program too ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
data = [
{
 "user" => {
    "name" => 'John',
    "age" => "36",
  },
  "company" => "Terminal"
  "country" => "Canada"
},
{
"user" => {
    "name" => 'Mary',
    "age" => "32",
  },
  "company" => "Brasco",
  "country" => "Italy"
},
{
"user" => {
    "name" => 'Andre',
    "age" => "32",
  },
  "company" => "Brasco",
  "country" => "Italy"
}]


data.sort do |a,b| 
  sort_direction = [a['company'],a['country']] <=> [b['company'],b['country']]
  b['user']['name'] <=> a['user']['name'] if sort_direction == 0
end
#=>=> [{"user"=>{"name"=>"Mary", "age"=>"32"}, "company"=>"Brasco", "country"=>"Italy"}{"user"=>{"name"=>"Andre", "age"=>"32"},"company"=>"Brasco", "country"=>"Italy"},{"user"=>{"name"=>"John", "age"=>"36"}, "company"=>"Terminal","country"=>"Canada"}]
```

Comment: `case [a1, a2] <=> [b1, b2]; when -1; -1; when 1; 1; when 0; b3 <=> a3; end` if you want to go this way

Comment: @VictorMoroz what are you saying in the comment? This works appropriately as is

Comment: you have two extra comparisons you don't really need, okay, I admit `case` is a comparison too, but looks cleaner

Comment: @VictorMoroz I see what you are saying because it is conditionally comparing them originally then re-comparing if the conditional is false. Thanks for the note and for efficiency I see the point although I disagree with the readability portion as I think case statements read poorly.

Comment: @VictorMoroz Editted to limit comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Possible way if you do it often:

```
class Reverser
  attr_reader :v

  def initialize(v)
    @v = v
  end

  def self.[](v)
    new(v)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    other.v <=> @v
  end
end

# Order by company DESC, country DESC, user.name ASC
data.sort_by { |a| [Reverser[a['company']], Reverser[a['country']], a['user']['name']] }
```